# Sencha Touch chart legend names change

Tags: extjs, charts, sencha-touch, legend, names

I want to change the legend names of the chart in Sencha touch. By default it gives the data store fields names. When I have change title of `yField` in ExJs it works, but in Sencha touch it does not work.

```
xField: 'name',
yField: 'data2'
title : ['dfb'],
```

How should I solve my problem? I want to change the legend names in Sencha touch chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the title, change the `title` inside `axes`.
And instead changing `yField`, change it like `title: ['MyDesiredName']`

Comment: No it's not work. it gives error called 'Unexpected identifier'. I think this method work for extjs chats. But it does not work with sencha touch charts.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code snipped is:

```
series: [{
yField: ['data1', 'data2'],
title: ['Title 1', 'Title 2']
}]
```

as posted by Steffen Hiller in [the Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136068-ExtJS-4-Charts-Custom-Legends). So the title attribute needs to be inside the `series` configuration.